# Tailwind + Angular does not accept class names generated by concatenation

Tags: css, angular, tailwind-css

I'm just trying to dynamically set my background color:

```
let color =
      this.table.state == tableState.FREE
        ? 'green'
        : this.table.state == tableState.BOOKED
        ? 'yellow'
        : 'red';
```

Or just to simplify it:

```
let color = 'red'
```

Then I just add 'bg-' and '-600' of the tailwind syntax:

```
this.TableUiConfig.color = 'bg-' + color + '-600'; // result should be 'bg-red-600'
```

Well, for some reason it doesn't work.

```
this.TableUiConfig.color = 'bg-' + color + '-600'; // DOES NOT WORK

this.TableUiConfig.color = 'bg-red-600'; // DOES WORK
```

When using concatenation:

[image]

Not using concatenation:

[image]

As I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66275291/12828765) I can use whitelist, so the purge thing doesn't care when I generate my own classes, (not knowing why it does it in the first place). Anyway, should I create a whitelist for all the classes I'm trying to use? Or is there another method to disable the purge?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tailwind transition delay arbitrary value only working for specific values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70734086/tailwind-transition-delay-arbitrary-value-only-working-for-specific-values)

Comment: safeList did thank you ( https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#safelisting-classes )

Answer (score 1):

Tailwind is unable to generate classes if you don't include the entire class name in your source: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names

Comment: well , i think that is not good at all , some times you need to do that . hope they can fix it.